# Active Directory, startingDate value (under Attribute Editor), how to set using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried below script but it returns an error

> The parameter is incorrect

`ABC` is an actual AD account on our AD.

```
Set-ADUser ABC -Add @{startingDate="20230417050000"}
```

I tried other suggestion from ChatGPT but still have no luck. May I know if anyone was ever able to do this?

Comment: There is no `startingDate` attribute so you need to clarify on what you mean. Unless this is a custom attribute in your Domain.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized it should be the custom attribute. Then may I know how to set it using powershell? TIA

Comment: Have you added `startingDate` to your AD schema? If so, what is its type (string, integer, date, etc.)?

Comment: AD doesn't really do custom attributes (Well it does, but not the way people expect. You must either use an existing extension attribute or formally modify the schema for the whole domain). You will do MUCH better mapping this to an existing attribute already available.

Comment: Have you tried to swap `-Add` with `-Replace` instead?